# Table CSS Issue

Tags: css, html-table

I have this in HTML:

```
<div class="dataBurst" title="What is the Matrix?">
    <table align="center" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td id="matrixTD">
                <span onclick="alert('Not Yet Online');" class="coredump" 
                    title="How Would You Know the Difference Between the Dream World And the Real World?">
                    Click for System Core Dump
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS I'm using:

```
div.dataBurst
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:500px;
    height:321px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:default;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9px;

    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hide;
    text-align:justify;

    scrollbar-base-color:#575757;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:#a6a6a6;
    scrollbar-track-color: #a6a6a6;
}


td#matrixTD
{
    text-align:justify;
    cursor:default; 
}
```

The issue is when I try to create a class/id using: `<table align="center" height="100%">`, it does not work; how can I implement this?

my site is at: http://guygar.com

Comment: Is this CSS generated by a software? because... cursor:pointer; cursor:default; what? on the same div two cursor values?

Comment: yes because IE ans Others see cursor differently.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean with "try to create a class/id" and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: <table align="center" height="100%"> "i want this in a CSS but it is not working."

Comment: What exactly is "this"? What is not working? Why are you using a table here in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After think about it for a while I think I slowly get what you are after: You want to vertically align the text "Click for System Core Dump" inside the div #dataBurst

I think you are thinking too complicate here. There is no real need to actually vertical align anything here, just give the div big top and bottom paddings:

```
<div class="dataBurst" title="What is the Matrix?" onclick="alert('Not Yet Online');">
     Click for System Core Dump
</div>

div.dataBurst {
    /* vertical-align:middle; -- not needed  */
    width:500px;
    padding: 150px 5px; /* First value is top/bottom, second is left/right. Adjust as neeeded. Replaces height:321px; */
    background-color:#FFF;
    text-align: center; /* replaces margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; because you are centering inline text here. */
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:default;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9px;

    /* 
       Remove following, since there is not overflow happening here anyway,
       so the scrollbar properties also become unnecessary - and wont work 
       like this in newer IE's anyway, as they require the -ms- prefix.

    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hide;
    text-align:justify;

    scrollbar-base-color:#575757;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:#a6a6a6;
    scrollbar-track-color: #a6a6a6;
    */
}
```

Also you need to decide which `title` you really want. I've removed the inner one, because it's probably overridden by the outer one anyway.

Comment: thanks, great tips. the only issue i would raise is that i need overflow as i will be adding huge texts once the user clicks the link inside the table/div.

Comment: You should have said that in the first place. This won't work in that case of course. You'll need to show more code of how you want to add the text and explain what you want it too look like when the text is added.

Comment: thanks. your guidence has been very usefull. others have been helpful also but you hit it as i require.

Answer (score 0):

**This works. The HTML:**

```
<div class="dataBurst" title="What is the Matrix?">
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td id="matrixTD">
                <span onclick="alert('Not Yet Online');" class="coredump" 
                    title="How Would You Know the Difference Between the Dream World And the Real World?">
                    Click for System Core Dump
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
div.dataBurst {
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:500px;
    height:321px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:default;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9px;

    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hide;
    text-align:justify;

    scrollbar-base-color:#575757;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:#a6a6a6;
    scrollbar-track-color: #a6a6a6;
}

table#table
{ 
    margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; 

}

td#matrixTD
{
    text-align:justify!important;
    cursor:default; 
}
```

And you should delete **cursor: default;** take a look here (only **IE 5.5** is not supporting **cursor: pointer;** but nobody is using it anymore.): http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html#t09

Comment: table#table { margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; } could you lay it out completely? ie declare one attribute at a time. thanks.

Comment: im new at this so i cant understand fully.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you want to move the attributes of table `align="center" height="100%"` to css? If yes then you have to delete this attributes from the table and add a class like this `<table class="mytable">`  when you do this, then in your css file you add the following rule

```
.mytable  {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you can change the class name in any name that you like (in html and css also).